# Emulating SOCD cleaner functionality with xkb

Tags: xorg, keyboard, xkb

I'm trying to emulate the functionality of standard hitbox SOCD cleaners with normal keyboard input. Specifically, I need it to:

- Space only: KeyPress Space
- s only: KeyPress s
- Holding s and Pressing Space: KeyRelease s and KeyPress Space
- holding s and space and then releasing space: KeyRelease Space and KeyPress s

Basically, at no point are both allowed to be considered pressed at the same time and if both are physically pressed at the same time it should be considered as only space being pressed. If both are held physically and then space is released it should consider it as releasing space and pressing s. I hope my explanation makes sense and isn't too convoluted.

If possible I'd like to achieve this with only xkb tooling and not any xdotool scripts as to avoid introducing latency.

Comment: You could try adjusting [this simple C program](https://github.com/it0946/socd) to fit your needs. It didn't quite work for me, though.